# Pygame window does not close properly when clock.tick in the loop

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a project and when I add the clock.tick to my main game loop, my pygame window doesnt close.

```py
def game_loop():
    """The main game loop that runs as the game runs. Returns when the pygame window is closed."""
    global running
    global timer
    while running:
        while timer > screen.fixed_fps:
            fixed_update()
            timer -= screen.fixed_fps
        update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():  
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                return
        screen.clock.tick(screen.fps)
        timer += delta_time()
    pygame.quit()
    return
```

When I click the X, the screen freezes until I let go, but unless I click the X in a very specific time frame( I usually need to click it 20 times to close) it doesnt work.

Comment: what does `fixed_update` do? (provide source code obviously), I'd guess it also calls `pygame.event.get`

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because of the way you are handling the QUIT event in your event loop. The `pygame.event.get()` function returns all of the events that have occurred since the last time it was called, so if there is a delay in your loop, the QUIT event may not be handled until multiple events have accumulated. To fix this, you should move the QUIT event handling code to the top of your event loop so that it is handled as soon as the event occurs. Also you could try to add `pygame.display.update()` after the event handling to make sure it is updated.

```
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():  
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
                return
        while timer > screen.fixed_fps:
            fixed_update()
            timer -= screen.fixed_fps
        update()
        screen.clock.tick(screen.fps)
        timer += delta_time()
```

Comment: All you have done is changed what gets executed first when the loop initially starts, how does it matter where the delay happens in all the other cycles? since it really doesn't matter for this type of thing (time delays) when they happen in the loop, they're gonna slow the entire thing down and this doesn't make sense regarding `pygame.event.get` either, if you click the X, the event will get passed to that queue eventually without having to spam click X